# ruby condition sequence

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

I was under the impression that conditions joined with && were executed in sequence, such that the following would return true:

```
a = "adasd"
> b = a && b.present?
 => false
```

Thoughts?

Thanks!
--Peter

- note:

  > b = a
  >   => "adasd"
  >
  > b.present?
  >   => true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say this:

```
b = a && b.present?
```

You're declaring `b` as a local variable but it will be `nil` until the right side of the assignment is evaluated. In particular, `b` will be `nil` when you call `present?` on it and the conjunction will be false making `b` false.

When you do this:

```
a = 'pancakes'
b = a
b.present?
```

`b` will have the value `'pancakes'` when you call `present?` on it so you get a true return from `b.present?`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [rails doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F)

present is checking for a variable to be non blank

As per assignment timing, ruby declares the variable in the scope as soon as it sees it, so b will be in the scope but with no value, so present will return false.

You should maybe compared this with `defined?`

```
a = "abc"
=> "abc"
defined? a
=> "local-variable"
defined? b
=> nil
b = defined? b
=> "local-variable"
```